# Should I migrate this question from Programmers?

Tags: discussion, migration

We've just had [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112764/what-is-the-user-experience-best-practice-for-an-alternative-to-popup-windows) on UX posted on Programmers.

At first glance it looks like a perfect fit for this site.

Should I migrate it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current answers don't fit over here and the OP will need to provide more information before we can effectively answer it. I left a comment suggesting he ask a new question on UX.